# How to use " some of + adj+noun" and " one of +adj + noun"

Tags: grammar, pronouns, nouns, relative-pronouns

I know we can say these sentences:

> ***They are some of my best friends.***
>   ***He is one of my best friends.***

Can we say these?

> ***They are some of my friends.***
>   ***He is one of my friends.***

Thanks so much!

Comment: Yes. What problem do you see with that? It's perfectly alright to say so.

Comment: Thanks so much for your kind help. My books say " some“ is not usually used as predicative. We can say : Some are the best students. But we can't say:  The best students are some.  right?

Comment: "The best students are some" is incorrect in every case. _Some_ can't "stand alone" without a referent. _Some are the best students_ would only be correct if a referent were provided, for instance in a question: **Q:** _"Among this group of students, are any the best?_ ... **A.** _"Some are the best students."_ (_Some **of them**_ is much more idiomatic.)

Comment: Thanks so much for your kind help, sir. But I can't find any rule about how to use it. Like we can say:" we are a group." But we can't say: "we are two "or "The wolves are a pack" right?

Comment: @moyeea That's right.  Determiners, like *some* or *two*, need to modify a noun phrase (though numbers can have other roles instead, in which case they could be alone).  So you can say, "We are two students," or "There are two of us," or "Here are some friends."  Words like *group* and *pack* aren't determiners -- they're nouns, and so can be used alone.  "We are a group."  "The wolves are in a pack."

Comment: @cbh Thanks so much for your help！ But can we just say： The wolves are a pack？ And  use it as modifiers like pack study？ pack observation？